# Python - Adding a individual value to multiple strings in a text file which end with consecutive numbers

Tags: python, string, file, text

I do have a little trouble working out this problem because I'm using it with an for-loop now.

I want to edit a text file:

```
Indicate somename X1
Random qwerty
Indicate somename X2
random azerty
Indicate somename X3
random qwertz
Indicate somename X4
random asdfg
Indicate somename X5
```

Here is the Python script I'm running:

```py
#for i in range (0,4):
with open('text.txt') as fp, open('text2.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in fp:
        number = 10

        if ('Indicate somename') in line:
            for i in range (0,4):
                string = str(i)
                if (string) in line:
                    print (string)
                    content = line.strip() + " value = " '%d' % (number)

                else:
                    content = line.strip()

        else:
            content = line.strip()
        fo.write(content + "\n")
```

The problem is the continues rewriting principal in here. It just re-writes from the original all the time. I need the original file to be as it is.

This becomes the output:

```
Indicate somename X1
Random qwerty
Indicate somename X2
random azerty
Indicate somename X3 value = 10
random qwertz
Indicate somename X4
random asdfg
Indicate somename X5
```

The for loops works from 0-4, so it will stop by number 3.

Does anyone has a solution for this problem? Tried quite a few things but always in results even worse than this.

The value is going to be different every time, because of an for-loop with function.

Comment: What is your desired output?